# Force process.exit() vs closing all open resources/sockets manually

Tags: node.js, sockets

Say, I have a Node.js application that connects to a web server. At some point in time, I need to end this application.

Now I have two options:

- Simply run `process.exit()`
- or closing the connection, cleaning up and then exiting

Of course, the first approach is much more brute-force, but it's also way less coding ;-).

Are there any disadvantages I should be aware of when doing it like this? In other words: Could this result in not-cleaned up resources, like still-open sockets (either on the client, or on the server)? Does this affect when the server cleans up its resources for this connection, or is this done immediately?

Comment: AFAIK still still causes a "clean" shutdown of the node process, so open resources (files, sockets) will be cleanly released to the client OS and the client OS will cleanly close TCP connections. So as long as the network delivers the final packets, there should be no open sockets waiting to timeout on either side. Commenting not answering because I'm not certain, and maybe in edge cases (many connections, OS starved for resources) this ceases to be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put myself the same question when trying to decide the best way to handle errors and I foud very useful the following:

1. http://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors

in particular the section "**The best way to recover from programmer errors is to crash immediately**".